# Negative select last rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have got `table` with columns: `INT AUTO_INCREMENT id, VARCHAR cell`

I want to select N rows, where N is difference between number of all rows (A) and some number of last rows (L) - i mean `N = A - L`, where L is `Constant`

In the other words, i want to make negative select of last L rows.

for example:

```
id  cell

1    cell1
2    cell2
5    cell3
10   cell4
20   cell5
```

if `L = 2`, then `N = 5 - 2 = 3`, so I want to select three first rows (1,2,5) in this case.

How to do this in mySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `cell` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `cell`)
VALUES
    (1, 'cell1'),
    (2, 'cell2'),
    (5, 'cell3'),
    (10, 'cell4'),
    (20, 'cell5')
;
```

Query:

```
select
t.*
from
t
left join 
(select id from t order by id desc limit 2) st
on t.id = st.id
where st.id is null;
```

Result:

```
| ID |  CELL |
|----|-------|
|  1 | cell1 |
|  2 | cell2 |
|  5 | cell3 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c4c2af/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Mysql Version: mysqlnd 5.0 returns error `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` I musn't update.